# Problema na execução do pyautogui no pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

codigo:

```
   import pyautogui
   
   pyautogui.alert("a")   `
```

o erro da execução;

```
NOTE: You must install tkinter on Linux to use MouseInfo. Run the following: sudo apt-get install python3-tk python3-dev
```

já rodei o comando que mostra na msg de erro, infelizmente não funcionou, rodei outros comandos como;  `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

estou em busca de soluções.

Answer (score -2):

Isso está acontecendo porque você não está rodando uma persão completa do python.

Minha recomendação é quando for fazer uma instalação de python, e não quiser preocupações, intalar o anaconda, que vai trazer praticamente tudo o que precisa.

Neste caso instale o pip:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Depois tente instalar essa dependência do seu projeto através do pip utilizando:

`pip install pyautogui`

O problema não está no PyCharm e sim no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento.